# Jupyter lab memory problem "Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED"

Tags: memory, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyter lab keeps crashing with this error  "Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED". `top -u` is showing an unusual usage of ~RAM 4.7 GB. There is a similar intense memory usage in chrome task manager also. I'm not running any memory consuming calculation.  The Notebook is running from a Linux server. The error doesn't seem to be notebook specific. I tried with an empty notebook.  It is also not browser specific, trieg Edge and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be linked to a jupyter lab extension jupyter-tabnine. Everything works fine uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Error Message in `jupyter lab` :
"Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED"

My Action:
Opening a big `CSV` file with the extension `jupyter-tabnine`
After seconds of loading, it turns to give the warning on the top

Badthing:
And the jupyter lab can remember the oppend windows(the big CSV)
so restart the jupyter lab will continue the Error

Solution:

```py
while CSV_page:
    restart jupyter lab
    click the `x` of CSV_page
    if CSV_page.is_shutdown():
        CSV_page = false
```